# Como crear una lista ordenada a partir de elementos clickeados

Tags: javascript

Una consulta sobre Javascript: Tengo 3 links:

```
<a class="link" href=""> blablabla </a>
<a class="link" href=""> blablabla </a>
<a class="link" href=""> blablabla </a>
```

Si yo hago:

```
<script>
let productos = document.getElementsByClassName("link");
for (i = 0; i < productos.length; i++) {
   productos[i].addEventListener("click", crearLista);
}
</script>
```

Cómo puedo hacer para que se cree una lista con cada uno de los links a los que el usuario le haga click?.

Que sea una lista ordenada en el html.

Comment: Mmmmm porque no pones una lista no ordenada?? `<ul></ul>` y dentro los elementos? Así vas a tener una columna que podes poner tipo `Selected` y ya en tu código obtienes tu arreglo y lo filtras(map) por columna seleccionada

Answer (score 1):

No se si te refieres a algo así:

```js
let productos = document.getElementsByClassName("link")
for (i = 0; i < productos.length; i++) {
  productos[i].addEventListener("click", crearLista, false);
}

function crearLista() {
  event.preventDefault();
    enlace = this.innerText
  lista = document.getElementById('listaOrdenada')
  lista.innerHTML = lista.innerHTML + '<li>' + enlace + '</li>'
}
```

```html
<a class="link" href="">blablabla1</a>
<a class="link" href="">blablabla2</a>
<a class="link" href="">blablabla3</a>
<ol id="listaOrdenada">

</ol>
```